# Xml - Find Element By tag using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying extract some data from a bunch of xml files. Now, the issue is the structure of all the files is not exactly the same and thus, just iterating over the children and extracting the values is difficult.

Is there a `getElementByTag()` method for python for such xml documents? I have seen that such a method is available for C#, C++ users but couldn't find anything for Python.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 22):

Yes, in the package [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) you can find the built-in function related to XML. (also available for python2)

The one specifically you are looking for is `findall`.

For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(some_xml_data)
all_name_elements = tree.findall('.//name')
```

With:

```
In [1]: some_xml_data = "<help><person><name>dean</name></person></help>"
```

I get the following:

```
In [10]: tree.findall(".//name")
Out[10]: [<Element 'name' at 0x7ff921edd390>]
```

Comment: `findall` only searches at the children level. However, I was looking for something that goes all the way to the bottom of the tree.

Comment: If you use `findAll` for the root element of the tree, it searches all subelements. You can also use it on the ElementTree object, instead of the root element, and then it also searches the root.

Comment: That does not work for me. It only searches the child level and nothing below that. Also, your syntax is incorrect in the answer you posted. Thanks!

Comment: @codepi You're right. Got it wrong. I edited with a fix.

Comment: How can I get the text of the `name` dean?

Comment: @Heinz - By using the `text` attribute of the element.

Comment: @DeanFenster I believe the correct syntax should be ".//name" in order to get any element named "name". "*/name" will only return grandchildren of the element.

Comment: @big_bad_bison is right; the correct syntax is `*//name` or ".//name".